# Reporting Services: Overriding a default parameter with an expression in a linked report

Tags: reporting-services, linked-list, parameter-passing, default, reportingservices-2005

So I've got a "daily dashboard" report in SSRS 2005. It has a parameter, @pDate, which defaults to "=Now".

I'd like to use this same report in a linked report to show yesterday's final dashboard (which would then be mailed out via subscription), and override the parameter default with another expression, "=dateadd(d,-1,Now)." But when I change the default parameter, I get a data mismatch error (natch).

I'm assuming that's the end of the line and I just need to deploy a copy of the daily dashboard report with a default @pDate of yesterday, but I thought I'd post here and see if anybody had some nifty shortcut to accomplish this without having to maintain two RDLs.

UPDATE: I found this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189700.aspx):

> If Default Value accepts a value, you
>   can type a constant or syntax that is
>   valid for the data processing
>   extension used with the report.

"Data processing extension" apparently translates to SQL server, so I tried valid singleton selects that weren't constants (GETDATE(), "04/27/"+YEAR(GETDATE()), etc...) and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out my issue: if you have subreports within your main report that are using passthrough parameters from the main report, **make sure that all of your parameters in your subreports are using the same data type**. Two of my subreports were using a String datatype for the @pDate field instead of DateTime, so the subscription was failing (although for some reason the live version of the report tolerates this inconsistency.)

I am now using a data-driven subscription to set @pDate dynamically and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you could try adding a second parameter to the report (without a default - call it `pDateOverride` for the sake of argument), and then change the default value for `pDate` to be an expression using the new value if it's present, otherwise Now().
Something like:

```
=Iif(IsEmpty(Parameters!pDateOverride.Value),Now(),Parameters!pDateOverride.Value)
```

You can then set `pDateOverride` when calling the report to generate yesterday's final dashboard.

Comment: Hey, this is a really nifty idea in general, but it just poses the original problem again: how to programmatically set pDateOverride with yesterday's date.